# Adding an error on a dynamic referenced field

Tags: sobject, error-messages

Is there a way to add an error on a dynamically referenced field? Let's take this simple example:

```
opp.get('Name').addError('Invalid name');
```

This is not working, I'm looking for a similar minded way.

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sadly I have to report the answer to your question is no. For me this is the final peace of Dynamic Apex to complete the ability to build truly 100% dynamic Apex libraries and solutions.

I've searched for workarounds and can find none, the [addError](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) methods on SObject use a highly specialised way to reference the field which is to hard code the field reference ahead of the method. Here is the Idea Exchange [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000GoC5AAK) to upvote!

> This method is highly specialized because the field identifier is not actually the invoking object—the sObject record is the invoker. The field is simply used to identify the field that should be used to display the error.

Comment: So I guess I will not be able to create dreamlike validation utility that I was wishing for... for now. Thanks Andrew for confirming my thoughts.

Comment: Yes sadly not for the moment....

Comment: Kind of hard to believe this still has not become reality.

Comment: And now with the advent of Lightning UI, we may never see this...

Comment: Even with Lightning it still makes sense to have the ability to add errors to dynamically selected fields. It is quite a bizarre state of the API to only allow this at the SObject, rather than field, level.

Answer (score 4):

## Winter '21 Update (v50.0)

Salesforce have finally added the ability to add an error to a field dynamically

We can now do the following:

```
String myFieldString = 'Name';
opp.addError(myFieldString, 'Invalid name');
```

Or, add as a Schema.SObjectField reference

```
Schema.SObjectField myField = Opportunity.Name;
opp.addError(myField, 'Invalid name');
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Worked like a charm.