# Is it possible to add Object fields into a list

Tags: fields, list

I want to add object fields into a list. The fields need to contain the data of a certain record. So suppose an Object X has 5 checkboxes. I want to add these 5 checkboxes to a list, BUT these checkboxes have to be connected to a record, so that I can change their VALUES.

[pseudo]

```
Opportunity o = [select isOne, isTwo from Opportunity where Id=:'someID'];
List<Field> fields = new List<Field>{o.isOne, o.isTwo};
for(Field f : fields)
    f.addError('Do something');
```

I hope you get my idea. 
So the question is how could I do something like that?

Comment: Do you want to change their values in the Salesforce db, in a Visualforce page, or some other place.

Comment: I want to add an error to the fields in salesforce. It should happen when a user saves the opportunity.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list of object (in this case Opportunities) instead. Loop through that and add errors to the fields in the list. They will be shown next to the particular field when trying to save the record.

```
For(Opportunity o : [Select isOne, isTwo From Opportunity Where Id = :'someID']){
   if(o.isOne == false) {
      o.isOne.addError('This checkbox cannot be checked');
   }
}
```

If you don't want to be refererring each checkbox field individually, you can fetch the field values dynamically in order to check them, but you won't be able to add errors to individual fields, since you need a field reference for that. I don't think you can create those in a List like in your example in the question.
Here's what you *can* do:

```
Opportunity o = [select isOne, isTwo from Opportunity where Id=:'someID'];
List<String> fields = new List<String>{'isOne', 'isTwo'};

for(String f : fields){
    if (o.get(f) == false){
        o.addError('Do something with checkbox '+f);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to save myself the effort to go over 20 if-else statements for all the checkboxes in record. Going over list of opportunities is not what I am looking for, but thanks for the advice! If you have another one, I will be happy to read it :)

Comment: Your field names should be Strings: `new List<String>{'isOne', 'isTwo'};`

Comment: tnx @BarCotter. Maybe I should have left the [pseudo] tag in there ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! As I see your code is adding an error to the whole Opportunity(on the top of the layout). Is it possible to add an error under every check box?

Comment: That's correct. I don't think that is possible in a variable way.. See also http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12761/adding-an-error-on-a-dynamic-referenced-field

Comment: I am going to use the if statements then :) Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: OK, update the answer with both options